# Which to chose Zend Framework or Symfony?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, zend-framework, frameworks

I used PHP/MySQL for a while, now I'm facing a new project, but in this case I have to use a PHP framework. In this project I have to develop a web application and a REST Api (Json) for Android and iOS applications. So which will be the best and the perfect for me.

Thank you guys

Comment: Thank you guys, after solid search, I chosed Symfony2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used symfony2 for my project and I found everything I need in. Also I created a REST Api with, and it works well. There are some specific bundles that can help you for your Api. Really I started with Zend, but when I tried Doctrine, I found that it works well with symfony2.

Hope that help you